# simple translation of simple text and question about 个 and 自己

Tags: translation

please translate the text below

1. 他有见兔正给山羊来送白菜
2. 我自己种的。只有自己种，才有吃不完的菜。
3. 青菜萝卜吃个饱

i have a little confusion in these sentences and about 自己 exact translation in second sentence

and the 个 in sentence 3

Comment: One user's attempt.１。He has (once) seen a rabbit feeding cabbage to the/a (?) goat。 ２。These were／it was grown myself。Only if I grow them／it myself，will I not run out of vegetables to eat（will there be vegetables I cannot finish eating）。 ３。（I am／they are）filled with （have eaten my fill of） greens and turnips。 Note that 个 can be used instead of 得 。

Comment: regarding 个 instead of 得 cf。＂实用现代汉语语法＂６０６页，六、用＂个＂连接的情态补语 用＂个＂连接的情态补语其形式和意义都很简单，远不如由＂得＂连接的补语那么复杂。这类补语有两种：（一）补语为肯定形式的，其作用一般是对施（当）事或受事进行描写，可由形容词（短语）、动词（短语）、象声词、固定短语等充任。例如：在游泳池里，孩子门又是游泳，又是打水仗，玩了个痛快。。。此类用＂个＂连接的情态补语比＂得＂连接的更加口语化，而且包含夸张的语气。此外，＂个＂前常用＂了＂，这一点与用＂得＂连接的补语很不同。（二）补语为否定形式的，通常表示＂不停＂的意思，其作用是对动作进行描写、说明。例如：１。妈妈见了高兴得笑个不住。２。。。，说个没完。３。。。心儿＂怦怦＂跳个不住。这两类补语都只能用在动词后。七、由＂得个＂连接的情态补语  由＂得个＂连接的情态补语只有肯定形式，其作用及结构特点与由＂个＂连接的肯定形式的情态补语基本相同。例如：其结果，把几千年封建地主的特权，打得个落花流水。。。这类补语多出现于文学作品中。

Comment: Reechen, you may use the answer box, that will be more convenient and readable!

Comment: The usage of 有 in the 1st sentence is not clear to me. Can somebody explain it?

Comment: google＂有＋verb＂，one result：http://www.italki.com/question/200801

Answer (score 1):

This old rabbit/goat story is an allusion to North Korean politics， right?

1。他有见兔正给山羊来送白菜。

1. He saw the rabbit give the goat a cabbage.

2。我自己种的。只有自己种，才有吃不完的菜。

2. I planted them myself. If you grow your own veggies then you will always have enough to eat.

Edit 2。 '我自己种的‘ could be written '这棵白菜是我自己种的‘，Chinese likes to shorten sentences. I'm not paranoid, I know they do it just to confuse poor me!

我自己种 = I myself plant = I planted (them) myself.

自己 = self, myself, yourself, themselves, depending on context.

3。青菜萝卜吃个饱

3. I'm full up with chop-choi and carrots. (this must be Kim Jong Un, the 胖子)

吃个包 = eat a fill = eat until you are full